# Alternate proof of Theorem 17.4 of Munkres's Topology.

Tags: general-topology

**Theorem 17.4:**  Let $Y$ be a subspace of $X$; let $A$ be a subset of $Y$; let $\bar{A}$ denote the closure of $A$ in $X$. Then the closure of $A$ in $Y$ equals $\bar{A}\cap Y$.

Here is my proof:

Step 1: Let $G$ denote the closure of $A$ in $Y$. This, by definition, means that $G=\bigcap_{\beta\in J} B_\beta$, where $B_\beta$ are closed sets in $Y$ that contain $A$ (remember that $A\subset Y$).

Step 2: Using theorem 17.2, each of these $B_\beta$'s can be written as $B_\beta=(C_{\beta}\cap Y)$ where $C_\beta$ is closed in $X$ with the additional requirement that each $C_\beta$ contain $A$ (because, for each $\beta$, $B_\beta$ contains $A$ and $Y$ contains $A$).

Step 3: Therefore, $G = \bigcap_{\beta\in J} (C_\beta \cap Y) = (\bigcap_{\beta\in J} C_\beta) \cap Y$.

Step 4: The closure of $A$ in $X$, is given by, $\bar{A} = \bigcap_{\kappa\in K}F_\kappa$, where $F_\kappa$ are the closed sets in $X$ that contain $A$.

Step 5: The question then is whether $\bigcap_{\beta\in J}C_\beta = \bigcap_{\kappa\in K}F_\kappa$?

Step 6 (thanks to Arturo Magidin):

For each $C_\beta$ there must be a $F_\kappa$ it equals to:  For a set $B_\beta$ that is closed in $Y$ and contains $A$, there is a $C_\beta$, a closed set in $X$, that contains $A$. Hence, this $C_\beta$ is equal to some $F_\kappa$.

For each $F_\kappa$ there must be a $C_\beta$ it equals to:  Let $F_\kappa$ be a set that is closed in $X$ and contains $A$. Since $A\subset Y$, there is a non-empty intersection of $F_\kappa$ with $Y$, which we call $B_\kappa$ (this $B_\kappa$ now contains $A$ [as it is in Y and $F_\kappa$] and is closed in $Y$). Hence, this $F_\kappa$ must be equal to some $C_\beta$.

Comment: Step 6 needs to be justified; just because the count is the same does not mean the indexed sets are the same. What you need to show is that each $C_{\beta}$ is equal to some $C_{\kappa}$ and viceversa.

Comment: Thanks, Arturo. What do you think now, @ArturoMagidin?

Comment: Again: you don’t want to show the *index* sets are equal. You want to show the family of sets being intersected are equal. I can have distinct families with the same index set. While that is what you *actually* do (showing that the constituent elements of the families are equal), casting it as a proof that the index sets are equal is incorrect, since just showing “same index set” would not establish what you want.

Comment: (Moreover, it makes no sense to talk about $J$ being contained in $K$ or viceversa; you implicitly define $J$ as just some set indexing a family of sets with some property; and you implicitly define $K$ the same way. There is absolutely no warrant for assuming that the indexing sets are both taken from some larger set. The fallacy of those assertions would become clear if your notation wasn’t misleading: for example, if you used $C_{\beta}$ for the first family, and $F_{\kappa}$ (using the french for “closed”) for the second family. No reason to assume they are the same sets.)

Comment: Aah, I see, makes sense! On the other, if my claim of "J=K" is ignored, does the proof of step 6 add up and make sense, @ArturoMagidin?

Comment: As I noted, yes: you want to show that each $C_{\beta}$ is some $C_{\kappa}$ and vice versa, which is what you seem to be doing.

Comment: Thank you so much, @ArturoMagidin . I now avoid using the same letter ($C$) for both the sets. Let me know if there is still a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it more directly: $\overline{A} \cap Y$ is *a* closed set in $Y$ that contains $A$, so $\operatorname{Cl}_Y(A) \subseteq \overline{A} \cap Y$ as the left hand closure is the intersection of *all* such closed sets.

Moreover, if $y \in \overline{A} \cap Y$, then if $O$ is an open (in $Y$) neighbourhood of $y$, write $O = O' \cap Y$ where $O'$ is open in $X$, and note that $O' \cap A = O' \cap (A \cap Y) = (O' \cap Y) \cap A \neq \emptyset$, as $y \in \overline{A}$ so also $O \cap A \neq \emptyset$ and so $y \in \operatorname{Cl}_Y(A) $ and we have equality.